# How to resolve message '... system lacks support for snapshot feature'?

Tags: apt

When I do "`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`", 
I usually get this message in my terminal:

> Sorry, your system lacks support for the snapshot feature.

How do I stop this message from appearing? How do I get my system to support it?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the entire thing without modification?

Comment: Under which version of which distribution?

Answer (score 4):

This means, you have btrfs and apt-btrfs-snapshot installed, but btrfs cannot be found by apt-btrfs-snapshot. 
Snapshots before updates can safe you lots of trouble, so it's worth it to fix. Thanks to [source](http://usalug.com/phpBB3//viewtopic.php?p=146923&sid=d6a6c932f148e2a873b9632439a78df8#p146923), this worked for me:

`sudo ln -s /bin/btrfs /sbin/btrfs`

Answer (score 0):

You are using apt-btrfs-snapshot probably. You can remove it and then you won't see it. Probably you want it to work but you may need to put more info in your question.